# Extract the primary key from a entity object in JPA 2.0?

Tags: java, orm, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

Let's say we have an entity object. Is there a way to extract a primary key from it?

I want to do something like this:

```
public static Object extractPrimaryKey(EntityManager em, Object obj) {
    return em.giveMeThePrimaryKeyOfThisEntityObject(obj);
}
```

Reason for that is to get an attached copy of detached entity:

```
public static Object attach(EntityManager em, Object obj) {
    return em.find(obj.getClass(), extractPrimaryKey(em, obj));
}
```

Is it possible? (I am using EclipseLink 2.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this will work:

```
em.getEntityManagerFactory().getPersistenceUnitUtil().getIdentifier(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Reason for that is to get an attached copy of detached entity:

Why don't you just use [`EntityManager#merge(T)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge%28T%29)??

```
MyEntity detached = ...
MyEntity attached = em.merge(detached);
```

What's the problem with that?